# Comparative Solubility of Double Salts

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, solutions, ions

Is there a tendency that could be used to generally forecast how a double salt might dissolve in aqueous medium compared to the simple salts of its constituents?

Example:

There is metal A, metal B and acid C.

The solubility of AC and BC are known. Could one use these as a rule of thumb to know what to expect from the solubility of say ABC?

Would it (1) Be fairly in between the solubilities of AC and BC? (2) Be fairly close to that of the least soluble among the two (3) Be fairly close to that of the most soluble among the two, or could it (4) exceed or lie beneath the solubility of the least soluble of the two?

Poutnik enlightened me on factoring in the possibility of double salts in another question which prompted this interrogation in my mind so I thought I'd make a separate question specifically for this topic.

Comment: I suppose there is no simple rule, it can be any from the 4 cases.

Comment: I doubt it can exceed the solubility of the two. Other than that, everything is possible.